# Using Entity metadata wrappers to change field value under hook_node_insert()

Tags: 7, entities, hooks

I am trying to change a field value inside both `hook_node_insert()` and `hook_node_update()` using EMW. It actually changes the original `$node` object that is passed to these hook functions but the change doesn't get saved at the end.

```
function mymodule_node_insert($node) {
  if (!_is_dynamic_type($node->type))
    return;

  $messagew = entity_metadata_wrapper('message', message_create('post', array('uid' => $node->uid)));

  //copy terms
  $nodew = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  //below loads a full taxonomy term
  $nodew->field_hidden_type = taxonomy_term_machine_name_load('event', 'hidden_type'); 

  $messagew->field_hidden_type = $nodew->field_hidden_type->value();//this actually works
  $messagew->save();
}
```

There are a few questions near to this one actually, but none of them addresses this precisely. [This one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/106114/12521) for example is a very good explanation of the mechanism but its suggestion it not use.

Here, one should not use $nodew->save(), because it causes infinite loop. I also played a little with module weight, that does not help either.

I also tried to change another entity reference field. No use.

I don't want to go with `field_attach_update()` because it is old-fashioned.

Comment: Try [`hook_node_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7)

Comment: Thank you @Clive. I am about to implement this. Everything points to this direction.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using the save the field isn't *ideal*.
For setting the field values you should use the [set()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.wrapper.inc/function/EntityMetadataWrapper::set/7) function provided by the `EntityMetadataWrapper` class.

```
function mymodule_node_insert($node) {
  if (!_is_dynamic_type($node->type))
    return;

  $messagew = entity_metadata_wrapper('message', message_create('post', array('uid' => $node->uid)));

  //copy terms
  $nodew = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  //below loads a full taxonomy term
  $nodew->field_hidden_type = taxonomy_term_machine_name_load('event', 'hidden_type'); 

  $messagew->field_hidden_type->set($nodew->field_hidden_type->value());
  $messagew->save();
}
```

On a side note, I see that there is not check on the node type, or any other parameters in the implementation of  `hook_node_insert`. Note that it will get triggered **every time a node of *any* content type is created**.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. `set()` and `=` are both same and `=` is preffered on account of code readibility. Pleaser refer to [http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/entity-metadata-wrapper](http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/entity-metadata-wrapper). Also, the first line calls a custom check function. I deleted lots of lines for better readibility.